# Cache Busting Js inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, caching, iframe, sharepoint

I have an html file that is embedded inside of a page in SharePoint. The html file is added to the page via an iFrame and has some referenced js files. I am noticing for some users, the js file is being cached and they have to clear all browser data to get the newest version. Is there a way to force the newest version of the files without the user having to clear cache. If I implement cache busting now (like add a version to the file) will that force users to get the newer version of the file?

Comment: Adding a version string as a URL parameter is a simple way of doing that, because the browser considers the *entire* URL (including the query string) as the cache "key".

Comment: Is there a list of browsers/OS that don't read QS?

Comment: ?? All browsers work that way. It doesn't have to be a version string; it could be a build timestamp or something like that. As long as it changes when you update the code.